# Chrome Extensions - Asynchronous XHR?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for any way to sending asynchronous requests via XHR:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Actually I'm trying to send requests just after page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://myserver.com/", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Get logged user
            username = $("div.user", xhr.responseText).text()
                    .replace(/.*\(([a-z0-9]*)\).*/, "$1");
        }
    };
});
```

But the user experience is really not good, it freezes until it gets data from myserver.com and just after that it displays the [popup window](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html).

Is there any way to first display the popup window and after that show some loading text/image to user and AFTER that start pushing requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery already then why not use convenient jquery ajax wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "https://myserver.com/",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data) {
        username = $("div.user", data.replace(/.*\(([a-z0-9]*)\).*/, "$1");
       }
    });
}
```

Put that script not inside `<head>` but at the end of a `<body>`. If it still freezes a page then try using `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(getData, 0);
});
```

Comment: I don't know why is Chrome behaving like this, but setTimeout(getData, 0); helped... :-)